# What Negative Kurtosis implies

Tags: data-science

I have a dataset and when I am computing kurtosis of the Target Variable I am getting the value as -0.94. 
What I understand is a high kurtosis implies a Heavy tail of the data and low kurtosis implies light tail. What I can decide on this negative kurtosis?

Answer (score 0):

Since the reported kurtosis is negative, your software must be reporting an estimate of "excess kurtosis," which is the ordinary kurtosis minus 3.0 (3.0 is the true kurtosis of the normal distribution). Hence, your negative estimate -0.94 tells you that that the combined tails of your data have less weight than the combined tails of a normal distribution.  (Here, "weight" refers to the fourth powers of the z-scores.)